# Cant extract the values from a table using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

First I select options from to different dropdown menus, later I click on the show button and then when trying to extract values from the html table, no element is found. Any ideas why?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')
main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)

# This works perfectly
driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")

dropdown_secciones = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select')

select_box_secciones = Select(dropdown_secciones)
select_box_secciones.select_by_value("1|308")


dropdown_circuitos = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbCircuitos"]')
select_box_circuitos = Select(dropdown_circuitos)
select_box_circuitos.select_by_index(1)

mostrar_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/input[1]')
mostrar_click.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('mainFrame')

# This doesn´t work. No element is found. 
for r in range(8,35): #from row 8 up to row 35
    for c in range(3,7): #starting in column 3 up to column 7
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]').text
        print(value)
```

No element is found when trying to extract values from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a piece of code you might be interested in.

I think, that it will be better to use BeautifulSoup for html parsing in comparizon to xpath manipulation.

The idea of below code is next:

- once we switch to the 'mainFrame' wait until 'table' is present.
- for each 'tr' element find all 'td' elements within, which have 'class' attribute (because those are ones that contain data)
- if number of 'td' elements is 3, get this data.

Pluses of this approach:

- you don't need to know specific time until table is present.
- you don't need to know specific number of rows, index of start or end.

In other words, it's just completely relative.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")

select_box_secciones = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cmbSecciones'))
select_box_circuitos = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cmbCircuitos'))
mostrar = driver.find_element_by_id('cmdMostrar')

select_box_secciones.select_by_value("1|308")
select_box_circuitos.select_by_index(1)
mostrar.click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('mainFrame')

while 'table' not in driver.page_source:
    time.sleep(0.1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
for tr in soup.find('table').find_all('tr'):
    row = tr.find_all(lambda td: td.has_attr('class'))

    if (len(row) == 3) and (row[0].text != 'Nº'):
        data = [td.text for td in row]
        print(data)

driver.quit()
```

Output of the above script is:

```
['P22', 'PARTIDO HUMANISTA', '117']
['A500', 'CORDOBA CAMBIA', '2.999']
['P217', 'ENCUENTRO VECINAL CÓRDOBA', '786']
['20', 'UNIÓN DEL CENTRO DEMOCRÁTICO (U.CE.DE.)', '21']
['3', 'UNIÓN CÍVICA RADICAL', '1.053']
['A830', 'FRENTE DE IZQUIERDA Y DE LOS TRABAJADORES', '611']
['P238', 'MOVIMIENTO AVANZADA SOCIALISTA', '35']
['A601', 'HACEMOS POR CORDOBA', '4.059']
['P57', 'MOVIMIENTO DE ACCIÓN VECINAL', '31']
['P191', 'VECINALISMO INDEPENDIENTE', '152']
['P200', 'PARTIDO UNION CIUDADANA', '135']
['A300', 'MST - NUEVA IZQUIERDA', '329']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at the table and the trouble is that some rows may have empty columns (try getting tr[9] and you'll see what I mean.

Also with the rows that do have the 3 columns with values, some have fewer td elements than others as you probably already know.

So you could keep your 8 - 35 range, but within that you can use the following xpath to get all columns that actually have text in (use find_elements to get a list)...

```
for r in range(8,35):
    columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[text()]'.format(r))

    if len(columns) > 0:
        print(columns[0].text)
        print(columns[1].text)
        print(columns[2].text)
```

The xpath should always give you 3 elements, one for each columns with text in. As mentioned some rows will be empty but you can easily handle that as the columns result will have a 0 count.

Comment: Heyy! Thanks a lot for the answer. I ' ve tried your code but I am still getting no output. Maybe I am not switching frames correctly? This is the output I get when switching frames (before extracting elements from the table): 

page = driver.page_source
page

output : '<html><head></head><body></body></html>'

Comment: Odd, is the count for columns 0? I think your switching is fine -  I don't get the elements without the last two switches. Let's try a simpler one, what happens if you try `text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[text()]')[0].text`. Try this just after the final switch i.e. not in the for loop. I'm using c# and chromedriver but I have the equivalent code of yours and it's working for me.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range... when trying that

Comment: I've done this in python and there's a few things to note. You should probably debug your code to figure this out. Firstly there's a delay for the table to load and that's why you are getting the IndexError - I got the same. For now you can add `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` to your code (there's probably a better way to do this but I'll leave that for you to decide). Secondly, the xpath in my original post didn't format the string so the 'r' value wasn't being considered. I've now updated the for loop. FYI this should get you started, but you need handle any error outside the question scope.